# Wont render without collection.on, confused

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-local-storage

I'm working on a Backbone.js project and I'm prettey confused about collection.on or so called binding.

Here's a bit of the code from my View.

```
initialize: function(){
        this.accCollection = this.options.accCollection;
        //Nothing shows without this line, which renders 3 times
        this.accCollection.on('all', this.render, this); 
        this.accCollection.fetch({
            success:function(){
                this.render;  
            }
        });
    },

    render: function(){
        $('.currentPage').html("<h3>Accounts</h3>");
        console.log(this.accCollection.models);
        //Render it in jade template  
        this.$el.html(this.template({accCollection:this.accCollection.models}));
        return this;
    }
```

So the thing i don't understand is why without this line it wont work. It works if I use on with 'all' and with 'add'. Is it something with my fetch which causes it to not render empty data first time and on the second on third it works because it has been filled up then? Confused!

```
this.accCollection.on('all', this.render, this);
```

Tell me if I need to provide with more info and i'll edit the question!

/Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

1. In a view, you should you `this.listenTo` (example below): this makes sure that events get undelegated when the view gets destroyed.
2. You're `success` callback does not share the view's context. `this` in your callback refers to the `options` object you're passing in, not the view or even the collection.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
initialize: function(){
    this.accCollection = this.options.accCollection;
    this.listenTo(this.accCollection, 'reset', this.render, this); 
    // Setting reset to true will trigger the reset event
    this.accCollection.fetch({ reset: true });
}
```